# .htaccess redirect index.html to index2.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess in a sub-subfolder and the following rewrite:

**Working in:** https://subdomain.example.com/sub/sub2/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}index2.html [R=301,L]
```

But when i only have one subfolder it is not working:

**Not working in:** https://subdomain.example.com/sub/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}index2.html [R=301,L]
```

How can i make it work with only one subfolder?

Comment: For both domains the index.html and index2.html are in the same subfolder (https://subdomain.example.com/sub/index2.html or https://subdomain.example.com/sub/sub2/index2.html)

Comment: What are `DocumentRoot` path for both subdomains?

Comment: Ah thanks, I just changed to %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} to %{REQUEST_URI} and it worked.